# Standard math environment for equally-spaced columns of expressions?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, amsmath

I often need a display environment which would let me easily present equally-spaced expressions in the same line, with content on successive lines appearing centred at the same x-coordinate as content on the first line. I can sort of get the effect I want like this:

```
\begin{align*}
x+y && e^{2 \pi i} && \sigma
\\
\text{First} && \text{Second} && \text{Third}
\end{align*}
```

But it's not quite perfect, as the 'columns' appear right-aligned, not centred.

Of course I can achieve this easily enough using an array. But then I have to set the spacing between the columns myself, which the align environment does for me automatically. I just wonder if any of the standard math environments can do this already. I would like to be able to code it like this:

```
\begin{myenvironment*}
x+y & e^{2 \pi i} & \sigma
\\
\text{First} & \text{Second} & \text{Third}
\end{myenvironment*}
```

Answer (score 2):

For equally-spaced columns (different from equal-width columns), you could put your contents in a fixed-width `tabular*` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,array,amsmath}
\begin{document}
​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​\lipsum[1]
\newcolumntype{E}{@{}c@{}}% begin-/end-column definitions
\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}E*{3}{>{$}c<{$}}E}
  & x+y & e^{2 \pi i} & \sigma & \\& \text{First} & \text{Second} & \text{Third} &
\end{tabular*}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
​
```

I define a new columntype `E` used merely as a spacer for the first/last columns. Also, the addition of `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` adds stretch before/after each column to space things out evenly across `\textwidth`. Using `*{3}{>{$}c<{$}}` allows for 3 similarly defined columns (centered `c` and typeset in math mode `$...$`).

[image: Equal-spaced columns in tabular*]

Of course, this requires you to know how many columns you want to typeset, since you're using the `tabular*` environment. Although this is not as noticeable, you might want to add `\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0pt}` and scope `{...}` it around your `tabular*` environment in order to remove the spacing caused by the `E` column type. For example the code

```
\newcolumntype{E}{@{}c@{}}% begin-/end-column definitions

{\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0pt}% No \tabcolsep
\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}E*{3}{>{$}c<{$}}E}
  & x+y & e^{2 \pi i} & \sigma & \\ & \text{First} & \text{Second} & \text{Third} &
\end{tabular*}}

\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}E*{3}{>{$}c<{$}}E}
  & x+y & e^{2 \pi i} & \sigma & \\& \text{First} & \text{Second} & \text{Third} &
\end{tabular*}
```

produces this marginal difference

[image: Small adjustments to tabular* environment columns via \tabcolsep]

Comment: Thanks Werner, that's a clever solution -- although it's still a bit clunky. I don't see why functionality like this isn't built into the gather environment, for example. Anyway, thanks for the answer!