# How to distribute narrow expressions along a line?

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment

I want something like this:
[image]

two narrow equations/words equally distributed along the linewidth. I used next code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{block}{My block}
\hfill$a+a=a$\hfill$a\cdot a=a$\hfill\phantom{.}
\end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As you can see I've used a `\phantom{.}` to force end of line `\hfill`. My question is do you know a better solution? Probably Werner's answer in [Standard math environment for equally-spaced columns of expressions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24740/1952) is a better way to do it, but I think it's to much code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TeX removes a glue item at the end of a paragraph, so

```
\hfill$a+a=a$\hfill$a\cdot a=a$\hfill
```

doesn't work. You have to use space that doesn't disappear:

```
\hspace*{\fill}$a+a=a$\hfill$a\cdot a=a$\hspace*{\fill}
```

(The one at the start might be `\hfill`, but it's good practice to use `\hspace*` when one really wants space at the beginning and at the end of a line).

Comment: Just what I wanted!