# How to horizontally top-align multiple \tikzpicture's without using \hspace?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing, horizontal-alignment

The use case I'm having is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{qtree}

\begin{document}

\Tree [.A B C [.D E ] ]
\Tree [.F [.G H ] I ]
\Tree [.J [.K [.L M M ] N ] O ]
\Tree [.F [.G H ] I ]

\end{document}
```

which due to `qtree`s clever horizontal alignment produces

[image: qtree]

Now, as `qtree` is limited to 5 branches, I'm using `tikz-qtree` and therefore essentially a tikzpicture:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree [.A B C [.D E ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree [.F [.G H ] I ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree [.J [.K [.L M M ] N ] O ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree [.F [.G H ] I ]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: tikz-qtree]

How can I achieve the same spacing as in `qtree`? So that each space between two `tikzpicture`s and to the borders is the same, without using any manual measurements. Also, alignment should be at the top, not bottom.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have many TikZ pictures you want align at the top you can use the `align at top` style defined as

```
\tikzset{align at top/.style={baseline=(current bounding box.north)}}
```

The `\Tree` macros of `tikz-qtree` check whether they are already in a PGF picture so you could simply write

```
\Tree [.A B C [.D E ] ]
\Tree [.F [.G H ] I ]
\Tree [.J [.K [.L M M ] N ] O ]
\Tree [.F [.G H ] I ]
```

and they would automatically align at the top.

But they are not spread along the horizontal space.

The alignment can be fixed by including `\hfill`s between the `\Tree`s/the TikZ pictures.
An additional `\hfill` is needed before the first and the last element.

To save typing I have introduced a environment `spreadTrees` that adds a `\hfill`before every PGF/TikZ picture and appends a last `\hfill\null` at the end of the environment. The `center` environment is included, though actually only needed for the vertical space the environment includes.

You can do the same without the `center` environment (for floats). This is what the `spreadTrees*` environment does. There is a slight different horizontal placement, though.

#### `\hspace*{\fill}` instead of `\hfill\null`

Here’s the definition of the environments according to the comment by [Ignasi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100870/how-to-horizontally-top-align-multiple-tikzpictures-without-using-hspace/100879#comment218814_100879) and the answer by [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43285/16595):

```
\newenvironment{spreadTrees}{%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\pgfpicture\expandafter{\expandafter\hfill\pgfpicture}%
    \center}{\hspace*{\fill}\par\endcenter}

\newenvironment{spreadTrees*}{%
    %\noindent % (if not only used inside floats)
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\pgfpicture\expandafter{\expandafter\hfill\pgfpicture}%
}{\hspace*{\fill}}
```

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\newenvironment{spreadTrees}{%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\pgfpicture\expandafter{\expandafter\hfill\pgfpicture}%
    \center}{\hfill\null\endcenter}
\newenvironment{spreadTrees*}{%
    %\noindent % (if not only used inside floats)
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\pgfpicture\expandafter{\expandafter\hfill\pgfpicture}%
}{\hfill\null}

\begin{document}%
\begin{spreadTrees}
\Tree [.A B C [.D E ] ]
\Tree [.F [.G H ] I ]
\Tree [.J [.K [.L M M ] N ] O ]
\Tree [.F [.G H ] I ]
\end{spreadTrees}

\hrule

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{spreadTrees*}
\Tree [.A B C [.D E ] ]
\Tree [.F [.G H ] I ]
\Tree [.J [.K [.L M M ] N ] O ]
\Tree [.F [.G H ] I ]
\end{spreadTrees*}
\caption{(Figure above)}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I'm impressed! That's really useful. :)

Comment: Some time ago, [egreg suggested](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43284/how-to-distribute-narrow-expressions-along-a-line) me to use `\hspace*{\fill}` instead of `\hfill\null` or similars at end of line.

Comment: @Ignasi The definition of `\null` is `\mbox{}`, so the last `\hfill` is not “at the end of a paragraph”. Anyhow, I have updated the answer with a `\hspace*` solution.

Comment: With that I cannot use a custom `\edge` anymore, it says "use of @edge doesn't match its definition".

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the following will help:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}


\begin{center}

hello\\[-\baselineskip]
\raisebox{-\height}{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree [.A B C [.D E ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}}
\raisebox{-\height}{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree [.F [.G H ] I ]
\end{tikzpicture}}
\raisebox{-\height}{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree [.J [.K [.L M M ] N ] O ]
\end{tikzpicture}}
\raisebox{-\height}{\begin{tikzpicture}
    \Tree [.F [.G H ] I ]
\end{tikzpicture}}\\
world
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: aligned trees]